# How to check size, scalar or vector

Tags: matlab

Title said it the most, but more specifically the question begin asked is...

"Your function should keep track of the number of times that it has been called

Your function will accept 1, 5 or 6 arguments and return 1, 2 or 3 values

All arguments must be either a scalar or a row matrix; you should check for this and print 
an error message and return with a 0 in the first return value if it is not true.

All arguments must be the same size: either they all must be scalars or they all must be 
row vectors of the same length. You must check for this and print an error message and 
return with a 0 in the first return value if it is not true"

Thats not the whole problem i assure you, but the part at which i struggle with the most. As in, i have no idea how to keep track of the number of times it's been called (with count maybe?) or have any idea how to check the argument whether or not this is a scalar or a row matrix. Also checking whether or not if they are the same size

I search up on how to do all this, no result. So therefore, i am going to assume this is not the basics.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get any results by searching? Here are some hints: You can use size function to check whether its a row matrix or a variable. A row matrix has one row and a scalar has one row and one column. See `nargin` in MATLAB help to count number of input arguments. Similary use size to check if they are equal size. Show us your work then people will clear your doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all basic stuff you just didn't search hard enough:

1. Keep track of the number of times with a `global variable`. Just increment it each time the function is entered. Alternitivly you can get a workspace variable with `assignin` and `eval`: [HERE for Global.](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/global.html) [HERE for assignin.](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) [HERE for eval.](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/eval.html)
2. Check input arguments with `nargin` which can be used to pass the inputs: [HERE](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html)
3. Differing number of outputs with `varargout`: [HERE](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html)
4. Use `size` or `length` to check the length of inputs. `disp` to display a message, set the first output and use `return` to return.

Hope this helps.